# Randomize divs with PHP echos in them

Tags: php, html, echo, shuffle

Normally when I randomize divs with every reload I use the following PHP snippet. However, in one section of my site this doesn't work, because the images in each div is echo from a PHP array which contains a number of specific images for that div:

```
 <?php
    $news_array1 = array(

    '<div class="div01">
    <?php echo display_random_img($array01); ?>
    </div>',

    '<div class="div02">
    <?php echo display_random_img($array01); ?>
    </div>',

    );

    shuffle($news_array1);
    for($i=1; $i<3; $i++)
    {
        echo array_shift($news_array1);
    }

    ?>
```

Does anyone how I can randomly display these divs? They remain black at this point, as the echo within the divs doesn't work anymore. It's getting a little frustrating...

Comment: *"They remain black at this point"* - Answer: error reporting will tell you where you've gone wrong. It's pretty obvious here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't open `php` in a `php` tag. By the way, why do you want to use `for` and `array_shift`? You could use `foreach` to handle this.

```
<?php
    $news_array1 = array(
        '<div class="div01">
            ' . display_random_img($array01) . '
        </div>',

        '<div class="div02">
            ' . display_random_img($array01) . '
        </div>',
    );

    shuffle($news_array1);
    foreach($news_array1 as $item)
    {
        echo $item;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Perry, I've been using this on my site in numerous locations now. It works flawlessly!